# Overload object comparison when adding to a set in Julia?

Tags: types, julia

Is there a way to overload how `Base.Set` does its object comparisons in Julia?

I tried overloading `isequal` and `==`, but my objects are still marked as different when they should be the same.

E.g.

```
type Test
    x
    y
end

function ==(a::Test, b::Test)
    return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y
end

Set([Test(2,3), Test(2,3)])
```

gives

```
Set([Test(2,3),Test(2,3)])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Set` is a kind of `Dict` with values of type `Void`: [ref](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/set.jl#L3)

```
type Set{T} <: AbstractSet{T}
    dict::Dict{T,Void}

    Set() = new(Dict{T,Void}())
    Set(itr) = union!(new(Dict{T,Void}()), itr)
end
```

And [Julia-lang documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/collections/#associative-collections) describes `Dic` type as follow:

> Dict is the standard associative collection. Its implementation uses
>   hash() as the hashing function for the key, and isequal() to determine
>   equality. Define these two functions for custom types to override how
>   they are stored in a hash table.

Check, [dict.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/dict.jl), and look for `ht_keyindex2()` and `ht_keyindex()` functions. Both will return an `index` only if these two conditions are `true`:

```
if !isslotmissing(h,index) && isequal(key,keys[index])
    return index
end
```

Where in the above: `index = hashindex(key, sz)`
Julia uses `hash()` function do the task of hashing:

> `hash(x[, h])`
>   Compute an integer hash code such that isequal(x,y)
>   implies hash(x)==hash(y). The optional second argument h is a hash
>   code to be mixed with the result. New types should implement the
>   2-argument form, typically by calling the 2-argument hash method
>   recursively in order to mix hashes of the contents with each other
>   (and with h). Typically, any type that implements hash should also
>   implement its own == (hence isequal) to guarantee the property
>   mentioned above.

So with these preparations it is obvious that overriding `Base.==`, is not the right & complete way to do the task, but

1. We need to override `hash()` function to return the same `hashindex` and
2. Instead of `Base.==` it is sufficient to override `Base.isequal`

**Code:**

```
type Test
    x
    y
end

Base.hash(a::Test, h::UInt) = hash(a.y, hash(a.x, hash(:Test, h)))
Base.isequal(a::Test, b::Test) = Base.isequal(hash(a), hash(b))
Set([Test(2,3), Test(2,3)])
```

The point is, although `Test(2,3) == Test(2,3) #=> false` it works as expected.

Comment: It is annoying having to overload both `hash` and `isequal`, I hope they change this: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/12198#issuecomment-122938304

Comment: Why do you suggest override only `isequal` and not `==`?

Answer (score 5):

There is a useful package for composite type comparisons, [AutoHashEquals](https://github.com/andrewcooke/AutoHashEquals.jl):

```
using AutoHashEquals

@auto_hash_equals type Test
    x
    y
end

X = Test(2, 3)
Y = Test(2, 3)
Z = Test(1, 3)

X == Y  # = true
X == Z  # = false

Set([X, Y, Z]) # = Set([Test(2,3),Test(1,3)])
```

However,  like @Gnimuc-K pointed out **"this macro is only useful for mutable types when they are used as immutable records."**

Comment: it would be better to add [the warning](https://github.com/andrewcooke/AutoHashEquals.jl) into the answer: **"this macro is only useful for mutable types when they are used as immutable records."**