# Why does push!() adds duplicate elements to a Set?

Tags: julia

When using a `Set` of a composite type in Julia, the `push!` function seems to add duplicate items to the set.  Reading the Julia standard documentation, I assumed that the `isequal` function would be used to test for duplicates.  I guess I misunderstood, so perhaps someone can help me out.

As an example see the code below.  In particular, I'd like to know why `t2` is added to the set, despite being identical to `t1`.

Any help is very much appreciated. Note: In my case two variables of type `t` are considered identical if the fields `x1` and `x2` are equal; the values of the remaining fields do not matter.

```
type t 

  x1::Float64
  x2::Float64

  b1::Bool
  b2::Bool

end

isequal( tx::t, ty::t) = (tx.x1 == ty.x1) && (tx.x2 == ty.x2)
==(tx::t, ty::t)       = (tx.x1 == ty.x1) && (tx.x2 == ty.x2)

t1 = t( 1, 2, true, true)
t2 = t( 1, 2, true, true)
tc = t1
tdc = deepcopy( t1)

[ t1 == t2   isequal( t1, t2)]  # ---> [ true true ]
[ t1 == tc   isequal( t1, tc)]  # ---> [ true true ]
[ t1 == tdc  isequal( t1, tdc)] # ---> [ true true ]


s = Set{t}()
push!( s, t1) 
push!( s, t2) # adds t2 to the set although t2 and t1 are identical ...
push!( s, tc) # does not add ...
push!( s, tdc) # adds tdc although tdc and t1 are identical
```

Comment: Does the explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936593/overload-object-comparison-when-adding-to-a-set-in-julia) about hashing answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that discussion.

Answer (score 7):

As DSM indicated, you simply need to add a method for `hash` for your type, i.e.:

```
hash(x::t, h) = hash(x.x2, hash(x.x1, h))
```

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I actually followed the example supplied with Andrew Cooke's AutoHashEquals package.   (https://github.com/andrewcooke/AutoHashEquals.jl)

Comment: That's a nice package, it did mention the issue if your type is not immutable, i.e. if you change an object in a `Dict`, it will be lost (and `Set` is implemented as a `Dict` in Julia). Is that an issue for you, or can you make your types immutable? Also, it doesn't seem to let you define `==` and `hash` only on a subset of the fields.